# Netezza to Google cloud

Tags: database, google-cloud-platform, etl, google-cloud-sql, netezza

Is it possible to transfer data from Netezza to Google Cloud? 
Volume: 3b lines, frequency: once a month. 
If yes, could you please point me towards a resource that explains how to do it?